# Записать один обект QJsonObject в другой

Tags: c++, json, qt

Мне нужно  записать один обект QJsonObject в  другой. Я создал   jsonObject  и мен нужно в  него записать childJsonObject

```
    std::unique_ptr<QJsonObject> jsonObject = std::unique_ptr<QJsonObject>(new QJsonObject);

    for (decltype(test->numChildren()) childIndex = 0; childIndex < test->numChildren(); ++childIndex)
    {

        std::unique_ptr<QJsonObject> childJsonObject = serialise(test->child(childIndex));

        jsonObject = childJsonObject; // тут выдает ошибку
    }
```

ошибка:

```
 error: C2280: 'std::unique_ptr<QJsonObject,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::operator =(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
with
[
   _Ty=QJsonObject
]
```

Comment: Если вам нужно записать дочерний json объект в основной, то зачем вы пытаетесь его присваивать? Получится же, что основной объект будет заменяться дочерним на каждой итерации. Конструкцию `std::unique_ptr<QJsonObject> jsonObject = std::unique_ptr<QJsonObject>(new QJsonObject);` проще записать `auto jsonObject{::std::make_unique<QJsonObject>()};`

Comment: @VTT а как  записать? Пример если можно. спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю, в родительский QJsonObject надо добавить массив дочерних элементов. Для этого внутри цикла нет необходимости использовать std::unique_ptr. Думаю надо сделать так:

```
std::unique_ptr<QJsonObject> jsonObject = std::unique_ptr<QJsonObject>(new QJsonObject);
QJsonArray children; // Массив для хранения дочерних элементов
for (decltype(test->numChildren()) childIndex = 0; childIndex < test->numChildren(); ++childIndex)
{
    //Добавляем дочерний элемент в массив
    children.push_back(serialise(test->child(childIndex)));
}
//Записываем массив как элемент родительского объекта, по ключу "children"
(*jsonObject )["children"] = children;
```

Единственное, я не знаю какой объект возвращает функция serialize, если она возвращает unique_ptr, то необходимо просто переписать

```
children.push_back(*serialise(test->child(childIndex)));
```

Извлекаем объект из указателя, и получаем заполненный массив.

Если же задача стояла просто в замене старого объекта новым, то:

```
*jsonObject = *serialise(test->child(childIndex));
```

или

```
jsonObject = std::move(serialise(test->child(childIndex)));
```

Comment: static std::unique_ptr<QJsonObject> serialise(const Component* component);

Comment: тогда надо использовать children.push_back(*serialise(test->child(childIndex)));

Comment: нет задача стоит  додать в jsonObject   children

Comment: Тогда вот представленный код решает задачу.

Comment: а  если так  записать: std::unique_ptr<QJsonObject> childJsonObject = *serialise(test->child(childIndex));
            (*jsonObject )["children"] = childJsonObject; а то  препод хочет чтобы мы все  делали через std::unique_ptr

Comment: Это конечно хорошо, но в данном случае это только потеря ресурсов, и скорее вред. Но можно сделать так:
std::unique_ptr<QJsonObject> childJsonObject = serialise(test->child(childIndex));
children.push_back(*childJsonObject);

Comment: но я так понял  нужно создавать QJsonArray children?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78182/discussion-between-r-mazgutov-and-dimaaf).

Comment: написал в чат с новым вопросом

Comment: У меня снова есть  пару вопросов. Написал в чат